# disconnect Android camera by using OpenCv

Tags: android, opencv, camera

i need help with android camera connection in my application by using OpenCv.. I try everything, my project in android studio compile without any error but when i turn on application it always crash with camera disconnection , any body ideas how to fix it ?
i got the error in Android monitor it is like :
 CameraService::connect X (pid 2279) rejected (invalid cameraId 98).
Camera #98failed to open: Fail to connect to camera service

manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

```
public abstract class MyCameraBridgeViewBase extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String TAG = "MyCameraBridge";
private static final int MAX_UNSPECIFIED = -1;
private static final int STOPPED = 0;
private static final int STARTED = 1;

private int mState = STOPPED;
private Bitmap mCacheBitmap;
private MyCameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 mListener;
private boolean mSurfaceExist;
private Object mSyncObject = new Object();

protected int mFrameWidth;
protected int mFrameHeight;
protected int mMaxHeight;
protected int mMaxWidth;
protected float mScale = 1;
protected int mPreviewFormat = Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA;
protected int mCameraIndex = -1;
protected boolean mEnabled;
protected FpsMeter mFpsMeter = null;

public MyCameraBridgeViewBase(Context context, int cameraId) {
    super(context);
    mCameraIndex = cameraId;
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mMaxWidth = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
    mMaxHeight = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
}

public MyCameraBridgeViewBase(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    int count = attrs.getAttributeCount();
    Log.d(TAG, "Attr count: " + Integer.valueOf(count));

    TypedArray styledAttrs = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase);
    if (styledAttrs.getBoolean(R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase_show_fps, false))
        enableFpsMeter();

    mCameraIndex = styledAttrs.getInt(R.styleable.CameraBridgeViewBase_camera_id, -1);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mMaxWidth = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
    mMaxHeight = MAX_UNSPECIFIED;
}
```

Comment: please post your code as well, did u add marshmallow permissions?

Comment: what are marshmallow permissions ? you are meaning manifest.i am using Api 17 in my project and OpenCV 2.4.11

Comment: @SimonaSmileyČisarova  Whats your targetSdkVersion ?

Comment: i posted my manifest i have only minSdkVersion

Comment: @SimonaSmileyČisarova Please post your app *build.gradle* cause if its 23 then it would be permission issue i hope so

Comment: sorry i posted my old version of manifest the minimal SDK is 15, i posted build.gradle but what u mean 23 ?

Comment: Could you post your code that initializes the Camera through OpenCV?There may be some devices that are not compatible with OpenCV, but I don't think that your device is one of them.

Comment: i post my code that implementing the interaction with Camera and OpenCV library